# Extent of file is different in same coordinate system

Tags: arcgis-desktop, extents

I have one TIFF file and one shapefile in the same coordinate system, but it's not overlapping. When I see the extent of both files both are in meters but they are very different.

[image: Tiff file extent]

[image: Shape file extent]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The first extent do not look like being in meters / UTM, maybe it is degrees and the projection information is wrong

Comment: My shape file should fall inside tiff file. But they are showing very different extents. So how do i solve it?

Comment: I re projected it to UTM, but I am getting the same extents as before.

Comment: which tool have you used to reproject?

Comment: Project raster in arcgis. I projected it to 1984 UTM zone 43N

Comment: Raster was bad reprojected. It can be watched easily from images.

Comment: @xunilk, how do i correct it?

Comment: By using adequately ArcGis reprojecting tool with your original raster. You need to start over with reprojection again.